# Zero function and normal derivative implies zero gradient

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, solution-verification

Let $S$ be a $C^2$ $n$-dimensional orientable manifold embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $u$ be of class $C^2$ on $U$ open and intersecting $S$.

Suppose:

- $u=0$ on $S\cap U$
- $\partial_\nu u =0$ on $S \cap U$, $\nu$ being a unit normal on $S$

> Is it true that $Du=0$ on $S\cap U $?

I think yes, and here is how I would go about it.

Pick $P \in S\cap U$, rotate everything so that $\nu = e_{n+1}$. Then take a $C^2$ curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=P$, $\gamma \subseteq S\cap U$ and $\gamma'(0)=e_i$, for an arbitrary $i<n$. This is possible since the tangent to $S$ at $P$ is now $\mathbb{R}^n\times{0}$.

By our assumption $u\circ \gamma=0$, so that $0 = (u\circ \gamma)'(0)=\partial_iu(P)$. Together with the hypothesis on the normal derivative the proof is complete. Do you think this is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks correct to me. The hypothesis $u = 0$ on $S \cap U$ implies that $Du(p)v = 0$ for all $v \in T_pS$. The second hypothesis then implies that $Du(p)v = 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} = T_pS \oplus \text{span}(\nu(p))$.